# 2 eternal souls 1 destroyed dm unaffected? Or destroyed

Tags: yu-gi-oh

If I control 2 eternal soul and 1 gets destroyed are the dark magicians destroyed or left unaffected due to the other eternal soul?

Answer (score 2):

Read "Eternal Soul", it says unaffected by your opponent's card effects. They would be destroyed in your scenario.